# Is there a better way of writing nested loops in clojure?

Tags: loops, clojure

Is there a better way of implementing nested loops in clojure?

As a beginner I have written this code of nested loop for comparing difference between dates in days.

Comparing this with nested loops in java using for or while.

```
(def my-vector [{:course-type "clojure"
                 :start-date  "2021-01-25"
                 :end-date    "2021-02-06"}

                {:course-type "r"
                 :start-date  "2021-01-15"
                 :end-date    "2021-02-06"}

                {:course-type "python"
                 :start-date  "2020-12-05"
                 :end-date    "2021-01-05"}

                {:course-type "java"
                 :start-date  "2020-09-15"
                 :end-date    "2020-10-20"}
                ])

(defn find-gap-in-course [mycourses]
  (println "Finding gap between dates....")
  (loop [[course1 & mycourses] mycourses]
    (loop [[course2 & mycourses] mycourses]
      (when (and
              (and (not-empty course1) (not-empty course2))
              (> (-> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit/DAYS
                   (.between
                     (LocalDate/parse (course2 :end-date))
                     (LocalDate/parse (course1 :start-date)))) 30))
        (println "Dates evaluated are =" (course2 :end-date) (course1 :start-date))
        (println "Gap of > 30 days between dates ="
          (-> java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit/DAYS
            (.between
              (LocalDate/parse (course2 :end-date))
              (LocalDate/parse (course1 :start-date)))))
        (do true)))
    (do false)
    (if course1 (recur mycourses))))

(find-gap-in-course my-vector)
```

Answer (score 5):

Learning to program in Clojure requires that one learn to think a bit differently because the tricks and techniques which people become accustomed to using in imperative programming may not serve as well in Clojure. For example in a nested loop, such as you've shown above, what are you trying to do? You're trying to match all of the elements of `mycourses` against one another and do some processing.  So let's define a function which gives us back all the combinations of elements in a collection <sup>1</sup>:

```
(defn combos[c]  ; produce all combinations of elements in a collection
  (for [x c  y c] (vector x y)))
```

This is a very simple function which matches all the elements of a collection against one another and returns the accumulated pairings.  For example, if you invoke

```
(combos [1 2 3])
```

you'll get back

```
([1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [3 1] [3 2] [3 3])
```

This will work with any collection. If you invoke `combos` as

```
(combos '("abc" 1 [0 9]))
```

you'll get back

```
(["abc" "abc"] ["abc" 1] ["abc" [0 9]] [1 "abc"] [1 1] [1 [0 9]] [[0 9] "abc"] [[0 9] 1] [[0 9] [0 9]])
```

So I think you can see where we're going here. Rather than running a nested loop against a collection, you can just create a collection of combinations of elements and run a simple loop over those combinations:

```
(defn find-gap-in-course [mycourses]
  (loop [course-combos  (combos mycourses)]
    (let [combi              (first course-combos)
          [course1 course2]  combi]
       ; ...processing of course1 and course2 here...
       (recur (rest mycourses)))))
```

But what if we don't want to consider the cases where a course is matched against itself? In that case another function to only return the desired cases is useful:

```
(defn different-combos [c]  ; all combinations where [1] <> [2]
  (filter #(not= (% 0) (% 1)) (combos c)))
```

Use whatever works best for you.

---

<sup>1</sup> About here the Clojure cognoscenti are probably screaming "NO! NO! Use [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/index.html)!". When teaching I like to give useful examples which the student can see, read, and learn from. YMMV.

Comment: Yes, I have to think differently here, combos is a good approach to get date pairs.Refinement will be, a combo of [{clojure, r} {r, python} {python, java}].
To answer your question, the data will be in periodical order of courses a student completed in 2020-2021. 
Clojure being the recent one and java the oldest.
So the code I shared was doing something to iterate through the vector in such a way that it will Compare dates like [{clojure, r} {r, python} {python, java}] and find if there are any gap between them.Like in java I was trying to comparing values of index[i ] with index[i +1].

Comment: Another option, if one *always* wants to ignore certain results of for, is to use a `:when` expression in `for`'s binding expression, rather than `filter`ing the result of `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write the above code, starting from my favorite [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  I have included some unit tests to illustrate what is occurring in the code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:import
    [java.time LocalDate]))

(defn days-between
  "Find the (signed) interval in days between two LocalDate strings."
  [localdate-1 localdate-2]
  (.between java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit/DAYS
    (LocalDate/parse localdate-1)
    (LocalDate/parse localdate-2)))

(dotest ; from tupelo.test
  (is= -5 (days-between "2021-01-25" "2021-01-20"))
  (is=  5 (days-between "2021-01-25" "2021-01-30")))

(defn course-pairs-with-30-day-gap
  "Return a list of course pairs where the start date of the first course
   is at least 30 days after the end of the second."
  [courses]
  (for [c1 courses
        c2 courses
        :let [start-1  (:start-date c1)
              end-2    (:end-date c2)
              gap-days (days-between end-2 start-1)]
        :when (< 30 gap-days)]
    [(:course-type c1) (:course-type c2) gap-days]))
```

with result

```
(dotest
  (let [all-courses [{:course-type "clojure"
                      :start-date  "2021-01-25"
                      :end-date    "2021-02-06"}

                     {:course-type "r"
                      :start-date  "2021-01-15"
                      :end-date    "2021-02-06"}

                     {:course-type "python"
                      :start-date  "2020-12-05"
                      :end-date    "2021-01-05"}

                     {:course-type "java"
                      :start-date  "2020-09-15"
                      :end-date    "2020-10-20"}]]
    (is= (course-pairs-with-30-day-gap all-courses)
      [["clojure"   "java" 97]
       ["r"         "java" 87]
       ["python"    "java" 46]])))
```

In the output, I left the names of course-1, course-2, and the gap in days to verify the calculation is the intended one.  This could be modified or extended for production use, of course.

In clojure we normally use pre-existing functions like `for` (technically a macro) instead of low-level tools like `loop/recur`.  The modifiers `:let` and `:when` make them extra-powerful for analyzing & transforming data structures.

Please see this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation),
especially books like Getting Clojure and the Clojure CheatSheet.